# How to compare two children of Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Based on the result of `data.key === "high_temp_coil"`, I am printing the data into my webpage with `data.val()` as shown below:

```js
var deviceRef = app.database().ref('/'+localStorage.getItem('machineid'));
deviceRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  if (data.key === 'high_temp_coil') {
    $('#high_temp_coil .value').html(data.val())
  }
  if (data.key === 'low_temp_coil') {
    $('#low_temp_coil .value').html(data.val());
  }
}
```

In my code `high_temp_coil` represents the high temperature of the coil and `low_temp_coil` represents the low temperature of the coil, each with their own fields in my database. However, due to a manufacturing issue, sometimes the high temp and low temps are backwards and I need to figure this out before printing the data. This is how I was trying to do that but it doesn't work:

```js
if (data.key === "high_temp_coil"){
  let valueh= data.val(); 
  if (data.key === "low_temp_coil"){
    let valuel= data.val()
    console.log(valueh);
    console.log(valuel);
  }
}
```

This is what the data looks like in my database:

```json
{
  "MachineNo": {
    "water": "value"
    "high_temp_coil": "value"
    "low_temp_coil": "value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the shape of your data in your question (preferably as JSON, but a screenshot of the console would suffice)? Trying to determine if your listeners would be firing correctly.

Comment: okay i will provide you the json structure of database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `child_added` event listener, your callback will be invoked whenever one of the children under that database location changes. Using this, you would need to store `high_temp_coil` and `low_temp_coil` in variables outside of the function so that you can compare them properly. Because you store the result in an element, you could pull the current values from there.

**Note:** In the below snippets I follow the convention of naming the `DataSnapshot` object as `snapshot`, reserving `data` for the plain JavaScript object returned by `snapshot.val()`. This aids in preventing confusion later on, especially when not using TypeScript.

```js
var deviceRef = app.database().ref('/'+localStorage.getItem('machineid'));
deviceRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.key === 'high_temp_coil') {
    const newHighTempValue = snapshot.val();
    const lowTempValue = $('#low_temp_coil .value').html();
    if (Number(newHighTempValue) >= Number(lowTempValue)) { // <- assuming the values are numeric and not written as "52.1°C"
      // new value is higher than current value
      $('#high_temp_coil .value').html(newHighTempValue)
    } else {
      // new value is lower than current value, swap places
      $('#high_temp_coil .value').html(lowTempValue)
      $('#low_temp_coil .value').html(newHighTempValue)
    }
  }
  if (snapshot.key === 'low_temp_coil') {
    const newLowTempValue = snapshot.val();
    const highTempValue = $('#high_temp_coil .value').html();
    if (Number(newLowTempValue) < Number(highTempValue)) { // <- assuming the values are numeric and not written as "52.1°C"
      // new value is lower than current value
      $('#low_temp_coil .value').html(newLowTempValue)
    } else {
      // new value is higher than current value, swap places
      $('#low_temp_coil .value').html(highTempValue)
      $('#high_temp_coil .value').html(newLowTempValue)
    }
  }
}
```

The main issue with the above code is that the `child_added` events would fire once on page load, and not get live updates from any sensors updating the data because these changes would fire `child_changed` events.

However, for your data structure, you can greatly simplify your code by [listening to `value` events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) instead. These listeners will be fired each time any of the data under that location is updated - including when a machine is created and any changes to the temperatures. Also, because the data is one level higher in the tree, you have access to the latest `high_temp_coil` and `low_temp_coil` values right in the snapshot. The trade-off for this listener is that you need to make sure to handle when the [data does not exist](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists) (`snapshot.exists()===false`) because `child_added` listeners would only be invoked when data is created where it is guaranteed to exist.

```js
var deviceRef = app.database().ref('/'+localStorage.getItem('machineid'));
deviceRef.on(
  'value',
  function(snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
      // TODO: handle machine does not exist
      console.error(`Machine ${localStorage.getItem('machineid')} does not exist in database`);
      return;
    }

    const data = snapshot.val();
    const highTempValue = data.high_temp_coil;
    const lowTempValue = data.low_temp_coil;

    if (Number(highTempValue) >= Number(lowTempValue)) { // <- assuming the values are numeric and not written as "52.1°C"
      $('#high_temp_coil .value').html(highTempValue)
      $('#low_temp_coil .value').html(lowTempValue)
    } else {
      $('#high_temp_coil .value').html(lowTempValue)
      $('#low_temp_coil .value').html(highTempValue)
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    // TODO: implement better error handling
    console.error("Listener was cancelled due to an error:", error);
  }
);
```